# To add a different timetable to the recyclerview in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm making a program that shows several timetable in a recycleview.
Specifically, what I want to do is show several different timetable.

(The image below is the goal)

[image: image1]

The open source address I referenced
'com.github.islandparadise14:Mintable:1.5.1'

My `MainActivity.kt`

```
package com.akj.except_support_libraries

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity :AppCompatActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val profileList= arrayListOf(
            casekt("timetable1"),
            casekt("timetable2"),
            casekt("timetable3"),
            casekt("timetable4"),
            casekt("timetable5"),
            casekt("timetable6"),
            casekt("timetable7"),
            )
        rv_profile.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
        rv_profile.setHasFixedSize(true)
        rv_profile.adapter=ProfileAdapter(profileList)


    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

casekt

```
package com.akj.except_support_libraries

class casekt(val number_text:String)
{
}
```

`ProfileAdapter.kt`

```
package com.akj.except_support_libraries

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class ProfileAdapter(val profileList:ArrayList<casekt>):RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfileAdapter.CustomViewHolder>()
{
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProfileAdapter.CustomViewHolder {
        val view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false)
        return CustomViewHolder(view).apply {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val curpos:Int=adapterPosition
                val profile:casekt=profileList.get(curpos)
                Toast.makeText(parent.context,"${profile.number_text}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProfileAdapter.CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.NUMBER.text=profileList.get(position).number_text
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return profileList.size
    }

    class CustomViewHolder(itemView: View) :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val NUMBER=itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        val TIMETABLE=itemView.findViewById<com.islandparadise14.mintable.MinTimeTableView>(R.id.TimeTable)
    }
}
```

`list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="timetable"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.islandparadise14.mintable.MinTimeTableView
            android:id="@+id/TimeTable"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [usages](https://github.com/islandparadise14/MinTimetable#usage) section I can see here you have to setup the `MinTimeTableView` with the required parameters

Please do so in the `onBindViewHolder` method of the `ProfileAdapter` class
Each `MinTimeTableView` can have different parameters which can be passed along the methods or constructors just like `number_text`